# Convert .cs file to .dll for execution of .asmx file on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dll

Trying to convert .cs file to .dll file for execute web service on my live server.

Now I am trying to convert .cs file to .dll file with visual studio command prompt but getting below error.[image]

Comment: Is the JobService.cs file in the folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`?

Comment: Actually I create .cs file from "wsdl http://localhost:52708/ServiceWeb/JobService.asmx?wsdl"  command from visual studio command prompt.

Comment: Thank you this problem is solved. Now I want to run my web service on my live server so other user can add my service reference on his website and use my service function. So have you any Idea how this is possible.